# Create table as select on Oracle using Jdbc creates table with no rows

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, oracle11g, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to execute a CTAS on Oracle 11g command using Spring's JdbcTemplate.

```
private void ctasTest(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    String ctas = "CREATE TABLE TARGET_DATA NOLOGGING AS SELECT ID,
      NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS CONTAINER_COLUMN FROM SOURCE_DATA";
    jdbcTemplate.execute(ctas);
}
```

When run against a new database TARGET_DATA table is created, but with 0 rows even though the SOURCE_DATA table has 1000 rows.

If I then use SQLDeveloper to drop the empty TARGET_DATA table, and run the same command, it is successful, and the table contains 1000 rows.

I can then drop the table and re-run my Java code and it will succeed and the TARGET_DATA will contain 1000 rows.

Is SQLDeveloper providing something in the background that I need to include in my Java code. I've tried the same thing in plain JDBC, and on Oracle 12c, and get the same results.

Comment: any exception ?

Comment: No exceptions, code completes without error.

Comment: so, are you saying it is not creating table at all ??

Comment: The target table is created, but with 0 rows.

Comment: Can you just run `SELECT ID,
      NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS CONTAINER_COLUMN FROM SOURCE_DATA` and see if you get rows ? I'm sure, you are using same user to get data in java code

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm creating the new table to divide millions of rows up into equal units of work for a Spring Batch job, so the CONTAINER_COLUMN needs to be persisted.

Comment: No. You didn't get my question, I said to do, to just check, if you are actually getting data when executing from java. A way to debug as you are not getting any exception and error

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood! As you suspected, running query that returned 0 results from my Java class. I've tried the same command in SQLDeveloper connected as the same user, and it returns 1000.

Comment: Now, I'm pretty sure, you are using different user, please cross check one more time

Comment: Definitely both connected as the same user.

Comment: As I don't have access to your datasource, so I can't (nobody can help you). Now, you need to investigate

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's helped me narrow the problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I hadn't committed my test data. Therefore it was still visible in the SQLDeveloper session, but not visible to the Java application.

Comment: Maybe this should be an edit or comment on your question, rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this as your statement:

```
String ctas = "CREATE TABLE TARGET_DATA NOLOGGING AS (SELECT ID,
  NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS CONTAINER_COLUMN FROM SOURCE_DATA)";
```

Notice that the select portion is enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: I don't think, it will make any difference

Comment: Thanks, I've given that a try, but unfortunately still get an empty target table created.

Comment: @user3130010 what do you mean by empty target ?? are you saying table is getting created ?

Comment: Yes, the target table is getting created.

Comment: @user3130010 then your SQL is getting executed and that also means there is no issue with the SQL

Comment: I'm suspecting it may be a bug in the JDBC driver, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: try executing the create table statement in sql plus or what ever tool you use to access the db.